# How to properly escape quotes for filepath and use in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file to:

1. Read a list of file paths from a text file.
2. Loop through each file path listed in the text file, and write the contents of that file to a new file.

The code below works if the configFilePointerFile path contains no spaces, otherwise, it fails.

If I add quotes around a file path with spaces (i.e. "C:\file paths.txt"), then it prints the file paths to the new file instead of printing the content of the files to the new file.

This script adds the contents of the files to a new file correctly:

```
set configFilePointerFile=c:\filepaths.txt <-- works as long as their are no spaces.
FOR /F "delims=" %%i in (%configFilePointerFile%) DO (
type "%%i" >>newfile.txt
>> newfile.txt echo.
)
```

This script adds the file paths to the new file only:

```
set configFilePointerFile="c:\file paths.txt" <-- doesn't work with spaces in file path.
FOR /F "delims=" %%i in (%configFilePointerFile%) DO (
type "%%i" >>newfile.txt
>> newfile.txt echo.
)
```

Any suggestions to get this to work with a configFilePointerFile which contains spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set "configFilePointerFile=c:\file paths with spaces.txt"
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%configFilePointerFile%") DO (
    type "%%~i" >>newfile.txt
    >> newfile.txt echo.
)
```